# reactjs - redux form and material ui framework — drag and drop file uploader

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building a nested form framework that uses the redux form and material ui framework -- I've built the components here to date - https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-darkness-npg7w?file=/src/Home.js

what I would like to do - is add an upload field - I've seen this example.
[How to enable file upload on React's Material UI simple input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40589302/how-to-enable-file-upload-on-reacts-material-ui-simple-input)

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  component="label"
>
  Upload File
  <input
    type="file"
    style={{ display: "none" }}
  />
</Button>
```

but in particular something that's more like a dragdrop. -- is there something that could be built more bespoke and cleaner without having to install another module that maybe has forced styles.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-dropzone

https://codesandbox.io/s/vj1q68zm25?file=/src/ImageUpload.js

---

[image]

---

--- old code

http://jsfiddle.net/5rbqehz3/1/

---- using the renderDragDrop starting file here -- adapt the code so that when the user drags a file to the area -- it populates the redux form field - textarea file type with the file --- if its a case of adding multiple files to the field -- or adding fields on the fly to house each file - uploaded.

its the integration part that I need to focus on -- if its a case of hiding from view the old school fields - but having them be populated in response to the drag and drop interface.

-- latest code 17th November 2020
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-darwin-dpdwj

22nd November - 2020

normal
[image]

on drag - the pink box appears and the dotted line animates inward
[image]

### I need help getting the styles right -- and cleaning up this code base

--- my current attempt -- https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-water-fpx38?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: I can't seem to get the file upload to register in the redux form when I submit - I think its cause I've not spread the operator in the field? - but it malfunctions because of setting the value? - https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-bash-5p07i

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698285/how-to-upload-file-with-redux-form

Comment: --- my current attempt -- https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-water-fpx38?file=/src/Home.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-darwin-dpdwj

Comment: In the last codesandbox it seems like you achieved what you wanted. The box changes it's color when you are about to drop the file. So what's the status of this question?

Comment: well - I had to make a standalone component in the works - because I can't append it to my current form framework.

Comment: I needed to adjust the animation and improve the UI

Comment: I think you can only tell the type of file it is - when it gets dropped - not during drag - so I've got to try and block it from handling unsupported files

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a out of the box solution for this. You can, as you suggested, add some packages that can be modified style wise, or make custom implementation. If you decide to go with custom implementation here is a useful [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/drag-drop-file-uploader-vanilla-js/) how to do it.

Comment: Thank you - I will check it out - one of the issues I was having was a failure to set the input - possibly because its just a regular html5 input and not part of the redux or material ui parts - I wasn't sure how to just get something basic going

Comment: You can catch onChnage event of input element and manipulate data in the way you need it. Also I think it does not meter if it is regular input tag or part of a material, it should work in both cases.

Comment: It was coming up with some error when I tried to get this working   https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-ishizaka-7wfr0  -- "Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string."

Comment: I've tried to get a basic file upload field to work - but its not getting picked up at all when I hit the submit button - https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-bash-5p07i  https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_file_upload_button.asp

Comment: but @Milan Milicevic I need to change the input -- not just pickup the onChange event from the input itself -- so when the user drags/drops a file - I want to change the input - programmatically

Comment: You can always set value property of an input. You can detect when user drag/drop something, handle with your logic, and set value of an input after that.

Comment: no - I don't think I am able to use my form framework - to change the file input -- I think its got to be stand alone -- cause its hooked in with the redux forms -- so I can't set it or attach the files to that field

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://css-tricks.com/drag-and-drop-file-uploading/) is an easy solution to what you want to achieve, it has both the auto submit and submit on click and it doesn't force style.

Comment: no it needs to be part of the form framework I've built -- I need something like this "$form.find('input[type="file"]').prop('files', droppedFiles);" -- but it says it won't work -- and I am trying to isolate the field with a ref

Comment: So @AKC - this means I can't use my form framework to house a draganddrop? It has to be a standalone component that uploads via ajax only - because you can't programmatically change the value of an input field?

Comment: @TheOldCounty this solution uses only html CSS and plain JavaScript, you can make it a standalone

Comment: @TheOldCounty also this solution has a guide on using ajax only

Comment: Yeah but it can't be used with my form framework right - I can't have the drag and drop change the input value

Comment: @TheOldCounty that is something you need to code, take the input as a blob

Comment: I don't think it will take hold in the redux forms - I am trying something standalone

Comment: @TheOldCounty it is very easy bro, just add whatever blob you want to add to `window.RANDOM_VARIABLE_NAME_YOU_CHOOSE` and you can easily access that variable from anywhere in any js file, so for example `windows.form_blob = someblob` now u can access it from anywhere, you don't have to store everything in redux, easy!

Comment: No I can't integrate the variable into the redux form framework that way